# Google Pie Chart show both Percentage and Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, pie-chart

How to display both Percentage and Values in Google Pie Chart ?

Comment: You can't display both on the slice labels, but if you set the `pieSliceText` option to `'label'` and the `legend.position` option to `'labeled'`, you will see the value on the slice and the percent on the legend label.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can set `pieSliceText` as `value-and-percentage` to display both **Value** and **Percentage**.

```
var options = {
   pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage'
};
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Please note that this option is currently undocumented (see [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?csw=1#Configuration_Options)), so please use at your own risk.

http://jsfiddle.net/6M2sH/301/

Comment: Where exactly do you enter this snippet in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

You can not display both on the chart labels.
For reference use [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?csw=1#Example)

Answer (score 0):

you can put `isStacked: 'percent'` in the option of your chart.

when mouse hover it will showing like this **10 (100%)**